# PHP MySQL pagination results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pagination

ive been fiddling with pagination and managed to get a version working based on a script, the code from the php cook book did not work.

The pagination i example i have working is from this site:
http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=289

I notice there are 2 queries, firstly to get total numbers of rows then to show rows, am not sure if i should be having 2 queries, another example on this site also shows 2 queries:     http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html

Contrasting information on the net and in books, should i be using 1 or 2 queries for pagination results? I do not want to continue to pick up others bad habbits so thought i would ask the pro's
Thanks

Comment: you only need one query. please post your code that your using here.

Comment: my code is a shambles tbh:
http://pastebin.com/Rr4W31zK
the script it is based on is:  http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=289

Comment: @Dagon Can you post an example of how to do this in one query? The only method I know is [link](http://jebaird.com/blog/php-mysql-pagination-one-database-query), but if the table is large enough it will be quite a blow to the server. Overall, I would recommend two queries, one for the total number of elements and one for the page records

Comment: Alexios thats exactly what i keep reading about, i am a minimalist and prefer tidy code if and where possible. am satisfied with my query then :) although the structure needs to be shortened. is it normal for pagination code to be very long on character length, well my example is abit longer

Comment: @AlexiosTsiaparas, see below guess that is 2 :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to get the total number of results and the current page of results using one query, but it's possible to use an easier method.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM ...;
```

And then

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Which returns the number of rows that were found (but not returned if there was a `LIMIT`) in the previous query.

Comment: no worries. :) @Renai as far as I know this is the best way to handle pagination.

Comment: i get abit concerned about my heavy use of if/else statements

Comment: @Renai it is not the same 2 as that demo you posted, which selects everything just to dao a row count. it's *far* more efficient to use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS()

Comment: above my pagination i require a 1-9 / A - Z character set the user can click to find shops start with that letter, what do i need to look at to attach this as part of pagination?  i manually created a-z but its poor, would like some direction please, thanks

Comment: So you just add another clause to your `WHERE`. For all things that start with 'A': `WHERE title LIKE 'a%' LIMIT 0,20`  and adjust the LIMIT based on the page. Does that make sense, or were you trying to make them like bookmarks in the total page navigation?

Comment: that sounds logical for what am after, am just concerned about the query string containing un used values,  surely the php comes in here somewhere

Comment: So, basically all you need to do is add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to the query where you select all of your matches, and then after running that query, run `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` which will tell you how many results the query **would have returned** if it didn't have a LIMIT